# Auto-indent destroying indentation of file

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, auto-indent

When I add newlines or paste, all my indentation will be destroyed. For example, this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ContactMassMailDto>()
            .Name("contact-mass-mail-grid")
            .Columns(c =>
            {
                c.Bound(m => m.Name);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax())
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

will turn into this, adding too many spaces:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ContactMassMailDto>()
              .Name("contact-mass-mail-grid")
              .Columns(c =>
              {
                  c.Bound(m => m.Name);
              })
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax())
              )
    </div>

</div>
```

...Why? How do I make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in ReSharper that causes the wrong formatting. Fix should be available in version 2019.2.1.

Also this behavior may be caused by turning on aligning of chained method calls. To turn it off, go to `ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Tabs, Indents, Alignment`, find a section `Align Multiline Constructs` and turn off `Chained method calls`.

Or you can disable auto indent on Paste. `ReSharper > Options > Environment > Editor > Editor Behavior`, set `Auto-format on paste` to `None`.

Comment: Nope... The only option turned on under that section is "Chained binary expressions.". Turning it off doesn't fix this.

Comment: Investigated. Seems that you hit a bug. Fix should be available in ReSharper 2019.2.1

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This issue has been bugging my whole Team for months. Great to hear it's going to be fixed.